# I can't paste copied PNG file to VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, copy, webstorm, paste, figma

I used to work with WebStorm IDE but later I converted to VSCode. My problem is that I can't paste an image (PNG file) from Figma desktop that I have copied.

I've checked and it works in WebStorm IDE but I don't have right path to solve this problem in VSCode.

I have checked all other solutions and used extensions like 'paste-img' but no result.

Comment: if VSC does not have the functionality write an extension or fix the extension or use Webstorm. VSC edits text not images.

Comment: I need more details so that I could answer your questions.

Are you copying an image you exported from Figma as PNG? Or did you copy the image from Figma using SHIFT+CTRL+C?

On VSCode, are you pasting to the left-hand File Browser? Because you cannot paste image binaries into text files.

Comment: paste to where? the Explorer View / workspace folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to paste files copied to the clipboard from other applications in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75406572/is-it-possible-to-paste-files-copied-to-the-clipboard-from-other-applications-in)